# user input to create object

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to create a **new object using a user input.** I tried assigning the user input to variables but **don't know how to add the variables** to the new object in the when I declare the new object. This is just the part of my code that i need help with. part i need help with is **line 8.** i know i can just put something random and when i use my set methods it will overwrite but that's not what I want. thank you in advance

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the name of the Soda: ");
   String soda = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Inventory count?: ");
   int product = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Cost of Soda?: ");
   double cost = input.nextDouble();
   SodaMachine one = new SodaMachine(String soda, int product, double cost);
   one.setCostOfBottle(cost);
   one.setInventory(product);
   one.setNameOfSoda(soda);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in how is `SodaMachine` class implemented. If the constructor of `SodaMachine` expects `String, int, double` parameters, call the constructor passing them without specifying the type. *Note* that it's not necessary to set (using `setCostOfBottle(), ...`) the members again, because that's why you are passing the variables to the constructor.

```
SodaMachine one = new SodaMachine(soda, product, cost);
```

---

If your constructor doesn't accept parameters:

```
SodaMachine one = new SodaMachine();
```

and set the members later:

```
one.setCostOfBottle(cost);
one.setInventory(product);
one.setNameOfSoda(soda);
```