# How to create an object using user inputs

Tags: java, input, constructor

I'm working on an exercise, I had to create a "User" class and to create a user using that class' constructor, easy.

The problem comes when the exercise tells you to create a menu which allows the user to create a new user.

I think I have to do something like this

```
System.out.println("Write the username:");
String username = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
```

And then something like this:

```
User newuser = new User("%s",username);
```

But I don't know how to do something like that. I know that syntax is not correct but I guess it should be something like that but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: why dont you just give a try first?

Comment: @JavaLearner1 I've been giving tries for a day now and looking for a way in the internet... I already did and I have limited time to do this...

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried..?

Comment: _I have limited time to do this._, this is completely irrelevant to us. Anyway, why not include the code you have so far in your question and also explain better what you mean with a menu.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805956/user-input-to-create-object) help?

Comment: @ejderuby This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!! :D

Comment: Please close your question if you found the solution to your question there :) Glad you found help.

Answer (score 1):

Putting everything together , i think this is what you are looking for:

- let's say this is your `User` class

```java
public class User {
private String username;

    public User(String username)
    {
         this.username=username;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
       return username;
    } 

}
```

- this is your `Main` Class

```java
System.out.println("Write the username:");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = sc.nextLine();//line 3
User userobj = new User(username);
```

What happens is that at `line3` you get the user input(let's say username) and you assign the value to a `String`

if you want to print the `username` simply do:

- in `Main` class:

```java
//... code
System.out.println(userobj.getUsername());
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userName = "John"; // or get the username from user
        User user = new User(userName);
        System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    }

}

class User {
    private String userName;

    public User(String userName) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the user input?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Scanner class for Console inputs and then the rest is easy. In Java you don't need to use formats like in C.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = sc.nextLine();
User user = new User(username);
```